# Laravel 5.3 - Sobre Mudar o Diretório App

Tags: laravel-5.3

Criei um projeto, dentro do projeto criei a minha própria estrutura de arquivos em vez de utilizar a pasta App, sendo assim criei uma chamada Massoterapia, na documentação informa que é necessário mudar o namespace e fiz o seguinte:

php artisan app:name Massoterapia

Agora o projeto além da pasta App, agora tem a pasta Massoterapia, mas quando tento utilizar as classes que estão na Massoterapia, fica sempre dando Class Not Found, mas o namespace e use estão certinhos, o que poderia ser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No arquivo `composer.json` altere:

```
"psr-4": {
    "Massoterapia\\": "app/"
}
```

para

```
"psr-4": {
    "Massoterapia\\": "nome_do_novo_diretorio/"
}
```

Comment: Só um detalhe que não sabia é que após editar o composer.json, seria necessário executar o comando: 

composer dumpautoload

Obrigado pela ajuda!